# Sinatra App - Separating Concerns

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, haml

Probably something really basic, but I want to be able to separate my Sinatra routes from controllers. I have this code in my `routes.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Server < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
   Action.index
  end
end
```

This is my `controller/server.rb`

```
class Action
  def sef.index
     @user = User.new("Abiodun Shuaib")
     haml: index
  end
end
```

It gives the error `undefined method 'haml' in Action:Class`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access method haml in class Action. It simply doesn't contain it. 
For example, you can do:

```
class Server
  def index
    @user = User.new("Abiodun Shuaib")
    haml :index
  end
end
```

By doing this, you will add to Server method index.

Or you can do in such way(it's called Mixin):

```
module ActionNew
  def index
    @user = User.new("Abiodun Shuaib")
    haml :index
  end
end

class Server < Sinatra::Base
  include ActionNew
  get '/' do
    index
  end
end
```